# Python, Selenium, webdriverwait until and timeexcepions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Hi I wrote a simple bot who paste ean code and searching a price.
Everything works fine till seearching ean code which has no result on the page.
Then bot stops program and show errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Tarnowski\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Tarnowski\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Tarnowski\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 269, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python\projects\main.py", line 53, in <module>
    ean.append(getdata(item))
  File "c:\Python\projects\main.py", line 29, in getdata
    price = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Anyone can help me fix this problem?
I want to search products one by another using ean's code
but when there are no such a code, skip this one or print "no result" and contiunue with next ean code.

```
eans = [
'5411183157583',
'5915081395316',
'5902431691770',
'3606489505943'
]
results = []

def getdata(symbol):
    PATH = ("chromedriver.exe ")
    driver.get(f"https://www.anyshop.com/result/?q={symbol}")
    
    price = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "price-value "))
        ) 
    name = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item-product-name "))
        )

    records = {
      'symbol': symbol,
      'price': price.text,
      'name': name.text
    }
    print(symbol + ' ' + price.text)
    return records

try:
  for item in eans:
    results.append(getdata(item))

except:
  print('no result')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rearrange your try/except block to be contained **within** your for loop:

```py
for item in eans:
    try:
        results.append(getdata(item))
    except:
        print('no result')
```

This way after you exit your `except` block, it will resume in the next iteration of your for loop.

I'd also recommend catching the specific exception `TimeoutException`, so if there's other errors, they won't get swallowed up accidentally. This just means importing the exception, and tacking that onto the `except` clause:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    ...
except TimeoutException:  # no other exceptions swallowed
    ...
```